# hiding empty columns in report server on page breaks

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report server data query

which returns following formatted table

```
 place1     col1    col2    col3   col4
surname1:  v1       v2             v3
surname2:  c1       c2             c3
```

then on the 2nd page

```
place2     col1    col2    col3   col4
surname3:  v1       v2      v3     
surname4:  c1       c2      c3
```

I want to hide col3 in first one and col4 in second one ( the empty ones )

I tried setting column visibility to

```
 =IIF(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!GradeValue.Value,"DataSet1")),true,false)
```

but it doesn't work, whereas if I set it to false<>true, it hides all the columns

I guess that's because it's a single query and my grouping is bad

but isn't there a way to hide empty columns on THAT page?

I have page breaks on places

row groupings on places and column grouping on col types ( they are up to 80 )

and max col per place is like 5

so I'm getting 75 empty columns each page :(

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a new list into your report and set it's Dataset property to your main dataset.
In the list insert a new page group on Place value and set it's page break property to Between each instance of the group.

Embed your matrix report inside the list (remove any redudant pages breaks/groups as they are handled by the list)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, I rewrote it using this, and I just had to add another grouping on columns to achieve what I wanted. really appreciated. thanks again :)